# Spatial Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial-query

I have a scenario where there are some pins and polygons spread across the map. Pins have coordinates (latitude/longitude) and the polygons consist of multiple vertices, which also have their coordinates accordingly.

My goal is to create a query which will group the polygons with the pins within.

I tried to generate (pseudo code below):

```
geometry::STPolyFromText(...polygon vertex coordinates combined...)
```

and then

```
generatedPolygon.STContains(geometry::Point (...pin's coordinates...))
```

but this resulted in a very slow query.

Is there any recommended way of approaching such scenarios?

Comment: Spatial queries are slow in general, as they are incredibly complex under the hood.  Do you have a spatial index on the table?

Comment: @iamdave not yet. I was trying to understand the basics of how it works, because I'm doing this for the first time. I have an idea to create a indexed column with the polygon (populated from the vertex coordinates every time a territory is added) and use it in the query, but not sure if it's OK to do so (for my scenario)...

Comment: Can you provide schema for your tables? I suspect it's going to be a pretty straightforward spatial join. Though if I'm reading your pseudo-code correctly, you're trying to generate all of the objects (points and polygons) on the fly. That is going to be slow not because of the data join but because creating all of those objects takes time.

Comment: @BenThul I have a table for polygons, a table for vertices containing polygon ID, and latitude and longitude for each point, and a table for pins, also containing latitude and longitude for the pin. what I'm doing is I'm joining the vertices latitudes and longitudes into a single 'POLYGON((...combined lat / long...))' and then calling STContains on that

Comment: So it sounds like what I suspected (that you're creating the `POLYGON` object at query time which is going to be slow). If the vertices for a given polygon are static, I'd suggest doing that calculation/generation of the `geography` instance once and saving it in your table of polygons as a separate column. Similarly for the pins (obviously storing `POINT`s).

Comment: @BenThul For testing purposes I called STContains on a hardcoded polygon instance, so no calculation/generation took place. yet the query took the same time. so, probably the spacial search is slow here and requires some tuning. Thanks for advice

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that the time is spent creating the geography instance. In your case surgically, the call to STPolyFromText.